# how to use array of linked lists for sorting a numeric array by bucket/bin sort?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

i have created a program to an numeric array by bucket sort. For that i have created a array of linked list
as per the bin sort method .

```
// Bucket or Bin sort 
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//Bin sort has linear complexity( O(n))

// node class
class node
{
public:
  int data;
  node *next;
};

// print array function
void
print (int arr[], int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
  cout << endl;
}

// max element of array function
int
get_max (int arr[], int n)
{
  int max = arr[0];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (arr[i] > max)
    max = arr[i];
    }

  return max;
}

// insert function of linked list at end needs head pointer
void
insert (node * head, int x)
{
  node *temp = new node;
  temp->data = x;
  temp->next = nullptr;

  while (head)
    {
      head = head->next;
    }
  head = temp;
}


void
Bin_sort (int arr[], int n)
{

  // max element of array
  int max_num = get_max (arr, n);
  int i;

  // double node pointer act as array of pointer of heads of linked lists
  node **bin;
  bin = new node *[max_num + 1];

  // pointing each head as nullptr
  for (i = 0; i < max_num + 1; i++)
    {
      bin[i] = nullptr;
    }

  // inserting value of array at position in linked list array
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      insert (bin[arr[i]], arr[i]);
    }


  // after filling linked lists array retrieving data to fill back in main array (arr) in sorted manner
  int k = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < max_num + 1; i++)
    {
      while (bin[i] != nullptr)
    {
      arr[k] = bin[i]->data;
      cout << arr[k] << endl;
      bin[i] = bin[i]->next;
      k++;
    }
    }

}


int
main ()
{
  int arr[] = { 3, 22, 34, 12, 15, 22 };
  print (arr, 6);
  Bin_sort (arr, 6);
  cout << "after sortion" << endl;
  print (arr, 6);
  return 7;
}
```

i tried to sort the array by bucket sort algorithm . i guess the error is when i create/insert a node to insert data it's not connecting correctly with the head node . so most probably the problem is in data insertion part .
here is an image of the algorithm[image: bin/bucket sort algorithm]

Comment: If your focus is on the sorting, don't bother yourself writing the data structures from scratch.

Comment: And if you have to write your own linked list, write the linked list. Test it exhaustively until you're convinced that it works. Then use it to sort. Don't comingle the two responsibilities. There's an old Unix guideline that says "Do one thing and do it well." Those who ignore that advice tend to write overly complicated code.

Comment: `using ArrayOfLinkedLists = std::vector<std::list<int>>;` -- Then use `ArrayOfLinkedLists` instead of your linked list / array code to test the sorting code.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks you for your valuable suggestion i firstly should have implemented linked list correctly, then should move on to sorting

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed in the insert method, though it's an easy mistake to make. What your algorithm is trying to do is go to the last node and point it to the newly created node. What it actually is doing is going past the end of the list and pointing a local variable to the new node. However, I would recommend taking advantage of linked list's constant-time insert by adding to the front -  create the new node, set it to point to the head, and set it as the new head, or something like that.

As to the program as a whole, the algorithm shown in that video is *counting sort*, which runs in O(max(arr) + n) time, where max(arr) is the maximum element in the array, meaning it's only useful for large data sets with small elements. Second, counting sort typically uses an array of integers to store the count of each element, not a linked list of identical elements. I assume that this is an assignment, I would recommend double-checking that it asks for a counting sort over a traditional bucket sort.

Comment: thanks bro so much , my sorting was correct but the fault was in the insertion function of linked list . and  i change my time complexity also by adding at head of list thanks for that also.